# Closing a div from within a div

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a listings page where each listing has its own div, the content for that div is loaded from a separate php script via a $.post

**The problem I have is trying to hide the listing, I think the problem may be something to do with this line**

$('div.close_listing')

only I can get it to work if I use

$('div.close_listing) (which works when I click anywhere in the listing div)

Any help much appreciated.

The html code for the listing is:

```
<div id='listing'>
   <div id='loading'></div>
   <a name='13'><h3>Business1</h3></a> <h4 data-id=18-3-3>Name Of Business 1</h4>
    <div>
        <hr>
     *** content forbusiness1 appears here ***
          <div class='close_listing'>CLOSE this listing</div>
    </div>

   <a name='14'><h3>Business2</h3></a> <h4 data-id=19-3-3>Name Of Business 2</h4>
    <div>
        <hr>
     *** content for business2 appears here ***
          <div class='close_listing'>CLOSE this listing</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The code to call the content is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('div.listing> div').hide();  
$('div.listing> h4').click(function() {
$('div.listing> div').empty().html('<img src="loading_image.gif" /><br>Retrieving Details.....');
$.post("http://www.example.com/record.php", { id: $(this).attr('data-id') });

$.post('show.php',{ id: $(this).attr('data-id')}, function(data) {
$('div.listing> div').html(data); 

$('div.listing .close').visible();
});

var $nextDiv = $(this).next();
var $visibleSiblings = $nextDiv.siblings('div:visible');

if ($visibleSiblings.length ) {
  $visibleSiblings.slideUp('fast', function() {
    $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
  });
} else {
   $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
} 
});

// closes the listing down

$('div.close_listing').click(  
function() {
$('div.listing> div').hide(); 
}); 

});
```

Comment: I think you accidentally hit submit before you were done.

Comment: Please check your question before submitting it. Obviously there is code missing.

Comment: as follows: ... ... and then?

Comment: I don't know what happened - I have entered all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You should go like this I think:

```
<a href="javascript:$(this).parent().hide();">CLOSE this listing</a>
```

if I don't misunderstand your purposes. :D

Comment: Why the heck did you make an another question?